# Horizontal dropdown menu in Bootstrap won't scroll with navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

today i ran into a problem with bootstrap while using a horizontal dropdown menu, it won't scroll with my navbar, obviously caused by this css-class:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:210px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But if i delete or change the `position:fixed` tag my dropdown-menu is vertical again...

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo"></a></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">mmenu1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">mmenu2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">smenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">smenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">smenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">smenu4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">smenu5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">smenu6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">mmenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo{
    text-align:center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    font-size:1.9em;
    font-family:verdana;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .nav > li{
    display:block;
}
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-inverse .nav > li{
    width:170px;
    display:block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:210px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is the visualized code in bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/cmjcUyHRTw

Is there any way to go around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that `width: 100%` means different things when position is fixed and when it is absolute. When it's fixed, it fills 100% of the window. When it's absolute, it fills 100% of its closest parent with relative positioning.

In this case, `li.dropdown` is relatively positioned, so the dropdown fills that width. To fix that, add this line of CSS:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown {position: static;}
```

Now fix your dropdown menu CSS with this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
}
```

Here is the fixed bootply: http://www.bootply.com/EuiK4NsMn5

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply that works nicely, also thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the width:100% on the .dropdown-menu is only expanding to 100% of an li element not the page.

Remove position fixed. Then add

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 600px;
}
```

and

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
```